# How do I dispose all of the controls in a panel or form at ONCE??? c#

Tags: c#, controls, dispose

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Form.Dispose() call controls inside's Dispose()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671013/does-form-dispose-call-controls-insides-dispose)

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Both the Panel and the Form class have a Controls collection property, which has a Clear() method...

```
MyPanel.Controls.Clear();
```

or

```
MyForm.Controls.Clear();
```

But `Clear()` doesn't call `dispose()` (All it does is remove he control from the collection),  so what you need to do is

```
   List<Control> ctrls = new List<Control>(MyPanel.Controls);
   MyPanel.Controls.Clear();  
   foreach(Control c in ctrls )
      c.Dispose();
```

You need to create a separate list of the references because Dispose also will remove the control from the collection, changing the index and messing up the foreach...

Comment: You can also use a reverse for loop, it won't mess up the indexes ;)

Comment: **Hint:** If you don't want to remove all controls but **only some of them,** instead of calling `MyPanel.Controls.Clear();` you can add `MyPanel.Controls.Remove(c);` to the `foreach` loop just before the `c.Dispose();`.

Comment: Disposing a panel will automatically dispose all controls within its collection. :|

Answer (score 4):

You don't give much detail as to why.

This happens in the Dispose override method of the form (in form.designer.cs). It looks like this:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a way to do this all at once. You can just iterate through the child controls and call each of their dispose methods one at a time:

```
foreach(var control in this.Controls)
{
   control.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't work in Winforms, the `foreach` loop will stop because the `this.Controls` collection has been modified. **The loop will exit early and not all Controls will have been disposed.** [`Control.Dispose()` removes the Control from its parent automatically when it's disposed](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,5919).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share if this were ASP.Net or Winforms. If the latter, you can do well enough by first calling `SuspendLayout()` on the panel. Then, when finished, call `ResumeLayout()`.