# Does Form.Dispose() call controls inside's Dispose()?

Tags: c#, .net

When I create a Form, the auto-generated code doesn't include an overrided Dispose method. Does that mean Dispose is not being called for all the controls in the form?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you call `Dispose` on the form, it will call `Dispose` for each control in its `Controls` collection. Those controls will in turn do the same, so in the end all controls' `Dispose` method should have been invoked. Note that this is not based on whether the controls are present in the designer or not; it is based on what control instances that are found in the `Controls` collection of the form at the time the call to `Dispose` is done.

The only case when I could see that this would not happen is if you create some container control yourself and override `Dispose` without propagating the call either to the base class or iterate over the contained controls and call `Dispose` on them.

Comment: Yup.  The components are done differently, that's what the auto-generated Dispose() method takes care of.  Removing a control from the Controls collection and not disposing it is a good way to leak.

Answer (score 4):

It should.  You might have to look in the YourForm.designer.cs file.  It will look like this:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
   if(disposing && (components != null))
   {
      components.Dispose();
   }
   base.Dispose(disposing)
}
```

The `base.Dispose();` call will take care of cleaning up the controls added to the Form.

Comment: That is not quite true; the `components` field is `null` unless you have non-UI components (such as a `Timer`, `HelpProvider` or `BackgroundWorker`) on the form. `components` handles disposing those components. It does *not* call dispose on other controls such as buttons, text boxes and so on.

Comment: Exactly, the form's controls are actually disposed via the call to `base.Dispose()`, namely inside `Control.Dispose()`. There is a lot more cleaning up going actually as you will see when looking into `Form.Dispose()` with Reflector.