# Dynamic flowlayoutpanel creation and dispose in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created flowlayoutpanel dynamically in windows form using c# . An i have added one button in that panel . Can anyone tell me how to remove that panel dynamically after the button as pressed? 
Here is the coding :

```
  FlowLayoutPanel[] flws ;
       Button[] butns ;

        for ( int i=0; i<3; i++)
          {    
            flws[i] = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            flws[i].Name = "flw" + i;
            flws[i].Location = new Point(3,brh);
            flws[i].Size = new Size(317,122);
            flws[i].BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;
            flws[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            butns[i] = new Button();
            butns[i].Click += new EventHandler(butns_Click);
            butns[i].Text = "submit";
            butns[i].Name = "but" + i;
            butns[i].Location = new Point(1100, 186 + brh);

            flws[i].Controls.Add(butns[i]);
           }
```

Comment: Please tag future questions with the framework you are using (I've tagged this with `winforms` because `FlowLayoutPanel` is only in `System.Windows.Forms`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with this really quick, hope it helps.

[Edited it to meet your requeriments].

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FlowLayoutStackoverflow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Load three FLP's
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var _flowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
                _flowLayoutPanel.Name = "Flow" + i;
                _flowLayoutPanel.Location = new Point(30*i, 30*i);
                _flowLayoutPanel.Size = new Size(300, 30);
                _flowLayoutPanel.BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;
                _flowLayoutPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                _flowLayoutPanel.Disposed += _flowLayoutPanel_Disposed;

                //Dispose Button
                var _button = new Button();
                _button.Text = "Dispose";
                _button.Name = "DisposeButton" + i;
                _button.Location = new Point(1*i, 1*i);
                _button.MouseClick += _button_MouseClick;

                _flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(_button);
                this.Controls.Add(_flowLayoutPanel);
            }
        }

        private void _button_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Button).Parent.Dispose();
        }

        //Notify disposal
        private void _flowLayoutPanel_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Disposed FlowLayoutPanel with name {0}", (sender as FlowLayoutPanel).Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) derives from [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) which is [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx). This means you should call [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) on the panel when you remove it:

```
private void RemovePanel(FlowLayoutPanel panel) {
    this.Controls.Remove(panel);
    panel.Dispose();
}
```

You don't need to worry about the `Button`s you've added to the panel, [because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671013/does-form-dispose-call-controls-insides-dispose)

> When you call `Dispose` on the form, it will call `Dispose` for each control in its `Controls` collection.

Comment: but i have to dispose the panel after the button pressed . Because button having some work to do ...

Comment: Do that then. I just wrote you a function that would properly remove the panel. It's up to you when do call it.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you keep `FlowLayoutPanel[] flws` in a form.
In the same way you added `flws` to the Form by `this.Controls.add(flws)`, remove it in the same way: `this.Controls.Remove(flws)`.
Remove it when the button is clicked, add the `Clicked` event to your form:

```
pubic class Form1: Form {
    FlowLayoutPanel[] flws;

    // ...

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Controls.Remove(flws);
    }
}
```